# GStreamer gst_pad_get_offset and gst_pad_set_offset not working

Tags: c, ubuntu, dynamic, gstreamer, offset

First of all I want to clarify that I do not speak English very well, so please apologize in advance if I do not express myself well.

**CONTEXT**

According to the command ***gst-inspect-1.0 --gst-version***, I have version ***1.14.5*** of gstreamer.

I started a dynamic gstreamer project whose simplified pipeline structure looks like this *(obviously I specify that I use a programming language and not gst-launch)*:

```
AnElementNoMatterWhich ! videomixer ! AnElementNoMatterWhich ! tee ! queue ! AnElementNoMatterWhich
```

Now imagine that after *10 seconds* I want to add an element, *no matter witch*, to the ***videomixer*** sink. Or let's say I want to add an item to the ***tee*** src (this is the same as with the *videomixer*, except that I would add a tail between the tee and the element so as *not to block* other branches).

It will take about 10 seconds before the stream passes into the sink pad of the videomixer . Likewise for the src pad of the tee. By analogy, the time spent before adding an element in a pipeline (and connecting it to the videomixer or to the tee) is around the same time that the videomixer and/or tee pads must wait before passing the stream.

This is all explained by the **difference** in execution of the pipeline compared to the newly created videomixer and / or tee pads.

This is where the two methods ***gst_pad_get_offset()*** and ***gst_pad_set_offset()*** come in.

**MY PROBLEMS**

- First of all I can not understand what the ***offset unit (gint64)*** is. Is it a unit of time ? Millisecond ? Microsecond ? Nanosecond ? Or is it something else ?
- Also I can't understand why ***gst_pad_get_offset()*** always returns **0**. However, I have to get the offset if I want to be able to set the right offset with the ***gst_pad_set_offset()*** method. According to the documentation I have to do it on a ***src pad***, but where ?
- And finally I don't understand why ***gst_pad_set_offset()*** is not working. I obviously run it on the sink pad of the newly created videomixer or on the src pad of the tee *(whatever)*. It doesn't change anything. Besides, if I have the idea of giving the value 10 (for example) to gst_pad_set_offset () and that I then run gst_pad_get_offset () on the same pad, I should theoretically have the value 10. However, I get always 0. It is as if gst_pad_get_offset () and gst_pad_set_offset () had not been implemented.

*I followed all the gstreamer tutorials and spent several days on the forums. I do not know what to do. However, I know that without the proper functioning of these two methods, my project is blocked. What can I do ? Do you have an idea ?*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Gst isn't well documented.

1. Nanosecond
2. By default, the offset is 0. You can change it and after it get_offset will return you the new value
3. You can use construction like this, for me it works (Gst 1.18.4):

```py
tee = pipe.get_by_name('t')
tee.srcpads[0].set_offset(1000000000)
```

In this example, first src pad of Tee will be delayed to 1sec.